# What are the verbs that need a gerund after “to”?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, writing, present-tense, conjugation

So could someone tell me what the verbs are that must have “ing” (gerund) after “to”? (a small list)

I know we have :  “look forward to”, “admit to”, “be opposed to”... but are there other verbs?

Comment: I look forward to a more detailed explanation of your question, along with some examples.

Comment: Is there a list of verbs that for sure need a gerund after the preposition “to”. 

-to look forward to
- to be used to...

Comment: What I meant is that, how do we know when a verb needs a gerund after “to”. Is there a rule to know that?

Comment: I think you are confusing a _gerund_ and a _present participle_. They have the same strtucture because they are the same word but a _gerund_ is actually a present participle functioning as a noun. In the case of the examples you give the present participle is still functioning as a verb. When I say "I look forward to meeting him" 'meeting' is an anticipated action. If I said "I look foreward to my meeting with him" then 'meeting' is a gerund becasue I am looking forward to an event.

Comment: Sorry if I’ve been mistaken about the terms, but my question is more about when do we know where to put “ing”. 

I look forward to meeting ( not “meet”) or we’re close to getting this reward (not get). Why do we put “ing”?

Comment: @BoldBen That is not correct.  When you look forward to meeting him, *meeting* is a verb whose direct object is *him*, and the whole clause is the prepositional object for *to*. In my meeting with him, *meeting* is simply a noun; it can even be plural if you have several meetings with him. Only the one with an object is a gerund, because gerunds are verbs whose clauses are used in substantive roles. They are not nouns.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for that, I was labouring under a misapprehension. This was because all the examples I have seen of gerunds have been verbs with no object such as "My hobby is gardening" or "Running is a good way to keep fit". I've obviously only seen the simpler definitions of a gerund.

Comment: @BoldBen It doesn’t need to have an object to be a gerund, but having a verbal object does prove it’s a verb of some sort. Compare ① *“Dogs barking all night **bothers** me.”* ② *“Dogs barking all night **bother** me.”* Notice how numeric agreement with the verb, *bothers* vs *bother*, changes its subject! In #1 the singular verb tells you that the **entire clause preceding it** is the controlling subject. That’s a nonﬁnite ‑ɪɴɢ clause headed by the singular *barking*. In #2 the plural verb tells you the subject has switched to plural *dogs*, with the ‑ɪɴɢ clause now acting in a modiﬁer role.